# Delete array element having object key value mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is my collection:

```
{
"_id":"5b3385af20b7dc2b008ef5b9",
"name":"C",
"distances":[{"_id":"5b3460b05b2edc1bbcb0f362",
"distance":7,
"waypoint":"5b3385af20b7dc2b008ef5b9",
"status":"available"},
{"_id":"5b3460b05b2edc1bbcb0f361",
"distance":4,
"waypoint":"5b3460a15b2edc1bbcb0f360",
"status":"available"}],
"createdAt":"2018-06-27T12:40:15.457Z",
"updatedAt":"2018-06-27T12:57:50.191Z",
"__v":0
}
```

Let's focus on the distances array only, so which is:

```
"distances":[{"_id":"5b3460b05b2edc1bbcb0f362",
"distance":7,
"waypoint":"5b3385af20b7dc2b008ef5b9",
"status":"available"},
{"_id":"5b3460b05b2edc1bbcb0f361",
"distance":4,
"waypoint":"5b3460a15b2edc1bbcb0f360",
"status":"available"}]
```

What i want to do is, I want to delete object and update the distances array which have `"waypoint":"5b3460a15b2edc1bbcb0f360"`

so far I have tried:

```
Model.update( {'_id': model._id}, { $pullAll: {distances: [{'waypoint': req.body.id}] } });
```

this isn't working. Please suggest a way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $pull of MongoDB

```
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { distances:  { waypoint:  req.body.id} } },
)
```

{multi: true}: adding this in above query will delete all entries matching { waypoint:  req.body.id}

Comment: It didn't worked.

`WayPoint.update({},{ $pull: { distances:  { waypoint:  req.body.id} } }, { multi: true });`

Maybe because the waypoint is an object inside distances array? don't we need to mention it in $pull ?

Comment: Ignore. I added call back to update function to see if there is any error, and now it is working fine :)